# Htaccess : Redirect url with get parameters

Tags: .htaccess

How can i redirect url with get parameters to a regular url :

from

```
/index.php?cid=100&id=550&Itemid=1084
```

to

```
/my-page
```

I tried :

```
Redirect 301  /index.php?cid=100&id=550&Itemid=1084 /my-page
```

but i didnt work

Comment: You certainly can redirect such a request to that target URL, however you will definitely lose those get arguments present in the first URL. I doubt that is what you want...

Comment: No i don't need this get arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you claim in your comment above, do *not* need the query arguments in the target request, you can do a simple redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=100&id=550&Itemid=1084$
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /my-page [R=301]
```

That rule will work in the http servers host configuration and likewise in a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess` style file).

If you want the matching pattern to be somewhat more flexible, so to accept arbitrary numbers, not just exactly those you specified in the question, then you can use a slightly modified condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cid=\d+&id=\d+&Itemid=\d+$
RewriteRule ^/?index.php$ /my-page [R=301]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: That's what i need ! Thank you for the hints.